# Compare inifinite resulting from limits

Tags: limits

Can one compare two infinites and determine wich is greater than?
Example:

$$\lim_{x\to 0+} \frac 1 x < \lim_{x\to 0+} \frac 2 x  $$

Comment: Infinity is *not* a number.

Comment: Infinity is **not** a Real number. You can include it in other sets like the extended Real numbers.

Comment: I imagine there might be a way to define a non-standard model which orders certain nonexistent limits by how fast the function that defined them grows. But I don't really see the point.

Comment: You could be evaluating the limit of their ratio (which could have a finite value), but you wouldn't be comparing "infinities" in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare infinities. You may have heard the phrase that "some infinities are larger than others" but it's deceiving to think in that way. What does happen however is that some functions "go to infinity faster". For example $f(x)=x^2$ goes to infinity faster than $g(x)=x$. It is true that

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=\infty
$$

But

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)-\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=undefined
$$

That is because infinities are not numbers to operate on. So you can't compare them either. However, the following limits defined and usually give valuable info about the way these values approach infinity.

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}[f(x)-g(x)]=\infty \\
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty \\
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=0
$$

The above expressions all show, in different ways, that $f(x)$ grows faster than $g(x)$ as $x \to \infty$.

For functions that grow with the same speed, e.g. $f(x)=x+a$, $g(x)=x$:

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}[f(x)-g(x)]=a \\
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1
$$

Lastly, some functions grow with speeds that are different, but of the same order, e.g. $f(x)=5x^2+2x+1$, $g(x)=3x^2+4x$.

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}[f(x)-g(x)]=\infty \\
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac 5 3
$$

An important note on the previous, always bear in mind that identities such as $\lim [f(x)-g(x)] = \lim f(x) - \lim g(x)$ are true only if both the latter limits exist and are real numbers. That is why sometimes $\lim [f(x)-g(x)]$ exists but $\lim f(x) - \lim g(x)$ is undefined.

EDIT for clarification: I used $x \to \infty$ as an example. It could be any other $x_0$ so that $x \to x_0$

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is pretty clear, the last part about the identities of limits was the thing that i didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

Look over the definition of the "Infinity" you are referring to. it is indeed not a real number, you can compere between functions and see who rise to infinity "faster" by their ratio

I assume we are talking about real analysis, so lets say that all functions are from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$

lets say that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\infty $ and $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=\infty $

if $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac {f(x)} {g(x)}=\infty $$ so $f(x)$ "go's to infinity faster" then $g(x)$

and if  $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac {f(x)} {g(x)}=0 $$

so its the opposite

in set theory you can encounter comparable infinity's in the form of cardinal and ordinal numbers. but its not the same "infinity" as you refer.